# Flutter: Change Todo text when extend a class from abstract class

Tags: flutter, dart, abstract-class

I have created abstract StatelessWidget. I declare a method calls `getHeaderImage` like below :

```
  @protected
  String getHeaderImage();
```

In child class that extends from my abstract class when override **getHeaderImage** appear this `TODO` :

```
  @override
  String getHeaderImage() {
    // TODO: implement getHeaderImage
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
```

It is possible to change text of  `// TODO: implement getHeaderImage`?? For example **// TODO: Should be SVG** or something that i want.

Answer (score 0):

The TODO comment is auto-generated to remind you to implement that function. Comments are for developers to read, they have no effect. So you can edit it or remove it, no worries. Learn more on comments [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#comments).